# YouTube API subscription insert always returns an error

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to Add a subscription for the authenticated user's channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Request Parameters :-

```
{ 
"0":
 {  "name": " <code>snippet.resourceId.kind</code>",  "value": "youtube#channel" },

"1": {  "name": " <code>snippet.resourceId.channelId</code>",  "value": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw" }

}
```

Response Parameters :-

```
{
 "error":
 {  "errors":
 [   {    "domain": "youtube.subscription",    "reason": "publisherRequired",    "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the <code>snippet.resourceId</code> property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to."   }  ],  "code": 400,  "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the <code>snippet.resourceId</code> property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to." }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This apears to be a bug in the Youtube api.  this can be verifyed by checking the api explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.insert?part=snippet&_h=1&resource=%257B%25220%2522%253A%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522snippet.resourceId%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%2522youtube%2523channel%2522%257D%252C%25221%2522%253A%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522snippet.resourceId%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%2522UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw%2522%257D%257D&) .

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "0": {
  "name": "snippet.resourceId",
  "value": "youtube#channel"
 },
 "1": {
  "name": "snippet.resourceId",
  "value": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
 }
}
```

Response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "publisherRequired",
    "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the <code>snippet.resourceId</code> property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the <code>snippet.resourceId</code> property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to."
 }
}
```

There is an [issue request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71688083) for this issue and the team has been pinged.

Comment: i have checked it with API explorer.Same issues i am facing. Let me know if any solution is available.

Comment: As its a bug in the API we are not likely to find a solution until Google fixes the issue with the API.  Sign the bug report should encourage google to look at it.

Comment: I did play with it a little trying to guess the property request format but wasn't able to come up with anything unfortunately

Comment: Any update on this issue? Still facing this issue and thousands of my users are complaining :(

Comment: same shit! I figured it out in console only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011575/youtube-subscriptions-insert-fails-with-error-400

Comment: apparently it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

[Link of Youtube Data API (V3), you can try here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert)

[it's the image example in "try this API" of how i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSaRs.png)

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "snippet": {
  "resourceId": {
  "kind": "youtube#channel",
  "channelId": "UCUK0HBIBWgM2c4vsPhkYY4w"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of your link here and don't write code-only answers.

Comment: Solved the problem!