# YouTube Subscriptions: insert fails with error 400

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to subscribe for a specific channel, to achieve this I use their [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#usage). There is a **Execute button** right on top page:
[image]

That supposed to demonstrate the request, after I grant access it throws an error:

```
    /**
 * API response
 */
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.subscription",
        "reason": "publisherRequired",
        "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the snippet.resourceId property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to."
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The subscription resource specified in the request must use the snippet.resourceId property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to."
  }
}
```

But the request body contains `snippet.resourceId` :

```
{"0":{"name":"snippet.resourceId.kind","value":"youtube#channel"},"1":{"name":"snippet.resourceId.channelId","value":"UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube API subscription insert always returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145010/youtube-api-subscription-insert-always-returns-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! To make it work we have to insert a value into `snippet.resourceId.channelId` gap, even if it already have one. I just copy/pasted the same value and bum code 200 and I was subscribed to google channel.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem! Can you please check in 2020? :D